# Date conversion in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have something like this:

```
2010-09-14 00:00:00
```

and would like to show only the month/year or something like this in the example above:

```
9/10
```

I was able to extract the Year part by doing this

```
select extract (year from E.DISCHARGE_DATE)as YR_NB
```

but cannot get the 9/10 result that I would like to see in my output result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select to_char(the_date_column, 'mm/yy') from the_table;
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html